# How to determine default handling for key events fired by a ListView

Tags: listview, javafx, event-handling

I would like to add an `KeyEvent` handler (or filter) for `KEY_PRESSED` events to a `ListView` for various `KeyCode`s and modifiers (shift and/or control key down). It appears that the `JavaFX` API provides default handling for most if not all of this, but I am unable to determine:

- Which events (and types) are handled, or
- How they are handled (how does the 'handling code' read?), or
- Whether the handling is implemented by way of a property setting (e.g. `setOnKeyPressed(..)` vs. `addEventFilter(..)`, or
- Whether it is possible to override/replace the default handling.

Is this information readily available? Is there a resource where these questions are answered in a 'plain english' manner? Or is it a matter of general policy for JavaFX development that these operations are off limits to developers and must be accepted on an 'as is, take it or leave it' basis?

Thanks in advance for any input on this.

Comment: Which events are handled by a control and what the control does in response is not documented. However, they follow standard UI/UX practices (e.g. shortcut+c means "copy to clipboard" for text input controls), even customizing themselves depending on the platform (e.g. on non-macs buttons can be fired by the "enter" key). The standard JavaFX controls are split into three parts: The `Control` subclass (the model), the `Skin[Base]` implementation (the view), and the "behavior" class (handles user interaction). You can look at the source code of the behavior classes to see what they do.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for your reply. I've looked at the behavior class (`ListViewBehavior`) as you implicitly suggest and what I learned is mixed. If you don't mind I can explain in more detail in a chat where the character limits don't apply as here. For others who may be interested, the built-in behavior is provided on an 'as is, take it or leave it' basis. If you want to deviate, you have to use a filter that consumes the event ..AND .. be lucky in guessing which event types to block; there's not much clarity in the API.

Comment: Behavior was meant to be extracted into public scope at the same time as Skin - but didn't make it due to unresolved api (and specification) issues. Since then the responsible developer left oracle and guess what happened to behavior dev .. ;) So you have options depending on whether or not you are allowed to use internal stuff: yes - access the behavior reflectively and modify its inputMaps, no - grab the sources from openjdk/jfx, modify the behavior and compile your custom fx. If both are off-limit, you can still c&p the skin/behavior and modify as needed

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks for your reply. Interesting info about the developer, that helps explain why some of JavaFX looks like a work in progress while other parts are outstanding. Your suggestions are well taken, but because most of the API that is involved here is restricted I don't see how they can work. Would be happy to explain in more detail, but that would require more space than the character limit here allows, so you would have to help me open a chat. On something different, did you once work on something called SwingX (or similar)? If so then I have something that might interest you.

Comment: yeah, have been one of the lead developers of SwingX :)

Comment: @kleopatra If you can explain how I can open a chat I have some info you may find interesting. I don't have much experience here, otherwise I would do it myself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209384/discussion-between-kleopatra-and-jfr).

Comment: "and what I learned is mixed" – if you post in the chat created by kleo then ping me here I can try to respond. But also consider if editing your question is more appropriate.

Comment: @slaw - Thanks for your reply and suggestion about editing the question. On reflection, answering it seems better than an edit. On a different matter, could you open a chat anyway? It concerns something that might interest you but doesn't relate to the question asked here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @Slaw's suggestion to edit the question it's seems best to provide an answer based on what I've learned.

The objective is to override the default handling for certain `KeyEvent`s that are sourced at the `ListView` level. If that is not possible, then it would help to know for certain *exactly* how the default handling works so that I have an idea of what I have to work around.

The JavaFX API appears to specify this handling in the `ListViewBehavior` class, which is restricted API, and because it’s restricted the easiest way to access it (in my experience) is through the `ListViewSkin` class which creates and holds a reference to the behavior class when `ListView` is created. This reference is a `private` field (there are no access methods, e.g. getBehavior()) and can therefore be accessed only within an instance of `ListViewSkin`.

The default behavior is installed in the `ListViewBehavior` constructor by way of a number of `KeyMapping` objects that are added to an `InputMap` (named `listViewInputMap`) by adding each mapping to an `ObservableList` (named `mappings`) for the map; the code for adding the mappings is in the `BehaviorBase` class which is the parent for `ListViewBehavior`.

@Kleopatra suggested several possible solutions that in theory would work except that all the classes apart from `ListViewSkin` are restricted API. This means that the behavior cannot be accessed in order to use reflection nor is it accessible from openjdk/jfx. @Kleopatra’s ‘copy-and-paste from the skin and behavior’ suggestion should be possible (I haven’t tried it) but is not practical; that would involve a mountain of work with at least 1000 lines of code (my guess) for something that should require no more than 30-50 … ain’t worth the grief.

Since the default handling cannot be overridden or replaced (at least not in a practical manner), then *exactly* how that behavior is installed and operates needs to be determined.

The behavior for the `KeyMapping`s mentioned above is specified in `private` methods in the `ListViewBehavior` class. The methods themselves are straightforward, and to that extent they are helpful. A number of points that bear on how the behavior operates are unclear, for example:

- There is no indication whether a particular behavior is added as a
  handler or a filter (i.e. `listView.addEventHandler(..)` or
  `listView.addEventFilter(..)`? This determines when the behavior
  actually runs, which in turn impacts on whether any countermanding
  custom behavior can be installed, and if so then where;
- The `EventType`s for which the behavior is added are not specified;
- There is no indication as to the order in which the behavior elements
  are added nor as to whether the order may depend on any undisclosed
  conditions; and
- There is no assurance that the behavior specified in the private
  methods mentioned above comprises all the built-in behavior.

This list may not be exhaustive, other areas may exist that someone else might consider as even more important. But these are enough to see how this leaves developers in a position where they have to fly blind, ... and for no good reason.

It would be unfair not to mention the fact that there is a way to prevent the default handling from running in favor of custom handling. This can be accomplished by adding a filter for `KeyEvent`s to the `ListView` that consumes the event. But this solution is not perfect inasmuch as the uncertainties listed above still remain. Also, will consuming the event have unintended side effects? Will it prevent default behavior from running when it should? In short, developers are still left to fly blind because these uncertainties can be clarified only through a tedious process of devising and observing repeated trial-and-error exercises to ascertain exactly what might be happening. Is this a good way to program?

Lastly, @Kleopatra’s remark regarding how the JavaFX behavior was intended to ultimately become public and what transpired is noteworthy. Based on my own observations here and in other areas, that information is not surprising. Indeed it goes a long way to explaining why JavaFX, while an excellent platform when viewed as a whole, nonetheless has a number of shortcomings that – unless addressed – will prevent it from effectively replacing Swing (which by way of reminder was one of its stated goals as enunciated by Oracle oh so long ago). That is an opinion that many experts who have forgotten more than I will ever know would certainly not only dispute, but vehemently; however, that does not change facts.

Comment: _private field (there are no access methods, e.g. getBehavior()) and can therefore be accessed only within an instance of ListViewSkin_ actually .. no :) there is no way to access it except via reflection (needs exports/opens both at compile- and runtime), from the skin or from somewhere else. Once you have that, the access of the behavior's inputMap is public (okay, of internal api) and you can replace the mappings with your own. That's common practice, highly implementation dependent, though.

Comment: and you missed the option to pull the sources of the openjdk/jfx project, replace the mappings of whatever behavior and compile your own version (described in https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX - it's no longer as ghastly as some years ago :) Then bundle and distribute with your own project.